# How to implement a Brokered Component: Windows Store App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, winrt-component

Using the instructions from here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/527286e4-b06a-4234-adde-d313c9c3c23e

Running Visual Studio 2013 as Admin with Update 2.

I create a C# BWRC project, TestBwrc.  In Class.cs I add an int property that returns 1.

I add a new project to the solution, a C++ Brokered Windows ProxyStub called TestBwrc.Ps.

I add a reference to the TestBwrc project, and set project Linker properties to Register Output.

I then build the solution.

I add a new project to the solution, a C# blank windows store app, called TestBwrc.Client.  I add a reference to the TestBwrc.Ps project.
Solution builds with no errors or warnings.

In the App.xaml.cs OnLaunched method I add TestBwrc.Class c = new TestBwrc.Class();
Visual Studio complains "Cannot resolve symbol 'Class'"
Solution builds with no errors or warnings.

Running the app throws an exception, TestBwrc.Class is not registered.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Also on TestBwrc.Client I added the Extensions tag to the app manifest with the ClassId of TestBwrc.Class and path Value of "..\Debug\TestBwrc.Ps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the path Value of "..\Debug\TestBwrc.Ps" in the ActivateableClassAttribute as mentioned in my edit.  Though %ProgramFiles% will be expanded, .. is not, nor is $(SolutionDir). So the for dev the only value that works is C:\dev\TestBwrc\Debug\TestBwrc.Ps

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="TestBwrc.Class" ThreadingModel="MTA">
          <ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" Value="C:\dev\TestBwrc\Debug\TestBwrc.Ps" />
        </ActivatableClass>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Comment: How do you then deploy this to a machine?  The path won't stay the same on the target device.  This is the part I'm struggling with at the moment.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Since these apps are "side loaded" by IT and not installed via the Windows Store, in our case we installed to a standardized location.  I then wrote a console app which is used by the solution after successful compilation to change the paths based on Debug or Release build.

Comment: A more flexible solution would be to use WIX or some other installer and write a real install program to resolve the paths.

Comment: And there is something special to do if I want to deploy the app in a tablet device? I have tried  all you have said and it runs in my windows machine but not in my WinRT tablet.